# Binary Search Algorithm from a Sorted list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

My algorithm is suppose to tell me if **'x'**(which has the value 5) is in the sorted array. However, I keep getting a 0. Well since my condition states that if 'x' is not in the array show 0. Where am I going wrong?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class binarySeacg {

public static void main (String[]args)
{
    int[] array = {10,7,11,5,13,8};
    exchangesort(array);
    binsearch(array,5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

}

public static void exchangesort(int[] S)
{
    int i,j,temp;

    for(i=0;i<S.length;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<S.length;j++)
            if(S[i]>S[j])
            {
                temp = S[i];
                S[i] = S[j];
                S[j] = temp;
            }
}

public static int binsearch(int[] S, int x)
{
    int location, low, high, mid;

    low = 1; high = S.length;
    location = 0;

    while(low<=high && location==0)
    {
        mid =(low + high)/2;
        if(x== S[mid])
            location = mid;
        else if(x < S[mid])
            high = mid -1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(location);
    return location;
}
}
```

Comment: BTW it should be `mid = (low + high) >>> 1;`

Comment: @user1883386 did you find your mistake ??

Comment: I have fixed accordingly but my IDE is not giving me results. It's neither stopping and just keeps running.

Comment: check my update and change your binary code search code to that one.

Comment: @user1883386 i really wondered, you accepted that answer, which no where matched your actual question. You really think, that was the only problem with your code ?? Nevertheless, its your wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are sorting an array and then the sorted array is used for searching the element.

And if the search is successful, then you do the below assignment

location = mid;  which means you are assigning the matching element's index to the location variable.

In this case, element 5 is in 0th index.

Hence you are always getting 0 on your STDOUT

Comment: you are little late, OP has changed his/her code a bit. Although, for current code,this is the reason.

Comment: Juz now I got time to look into this

Comment: Thank you guys !! All your input has been ++ !! And yes 5 is in the 0th index ! I guess I have to just change the index so it starts from 1 to n. Thank you all !!

Answer (score 2):

You set `low = 1;`, and 5 is the minimal element - so it is in index 0 - so in the sublist of [1,S.length] - it is indeed not there.

You should set `low = 0;`, and start from the first element - not the second. (Remember that index in java starts from 0, not 1).

(PS, note that in this specific case - the algorithm is correct, since in the sorted list - 5 is in the index 0).

Answer (score 1):

Because, you are trying to find `x` value, which you are passing `3` and in your list. It is not present. So, change it to other value like `5` and then try.

Also, you should start `low=0` instead of `low=1`. Because, it will miss the first element all the time.

```
public static int binsearch(int[] S, int x)
{
    int location, low, high, mid;

    low = 0; high = S.length;
    location = 0;

    while(low<=high && location==0)
    {
        mid =(low + high)/2;
        if(x == S[mid])
        {
            location = mid;break;
        } 
        else if (x < S[mid])
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(location);
    return location;
}
```

**Note :**  For the different output, change the value `binsearch(array,5);` here, which is called from `main()` method. Remember, change the value, which are present in your list.

Answer (score 0):

1. in java and most languages, the index starts from 0, not 1, and ends at n-1, not n
2. for binary search, check carefully about when exiting the while loop, and always remember the meaning of your low and high variables, whether it is [low, high], or [low, high)
3. for this specific problem, u should also consider what if there r duplicates in the array. whether to return the first element or anyone in the array